# Flash application poor performance in parent container

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have created flash game. When I debug it in locally in FlashDevelop everything is well. Spinning images are looking well. The performance is good. As well I have tried it in html trough embedding and it worked well in browser too.
But I have flash menu loader in my webapp. Flash menu loads my swf games.  The performance is very bad(Spinning images are slowed) when I play games after loading them in menu.
What is the reason of bad performance in parent container? The frame rate of menu and games is the same(30 fps).

Answer (score 0):

You need to profile your SWF to see exactly what's taking the resources. I suggest you to use Adobe Scout for this task.

To enabled advanced telemetry data in FD see this topic: http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=10322

Or you can always download Flash Builder to enable the telemetry data.

Comment: What's your HTML wmode? For example wmode=transparent would always run  slower.

Comment: Yes its transaprent. Ok I try to change it. When I run game after loading in fullscreen mode the performance is dood too.